# Webpage does not fill the whole screen on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

When I view the html file on my mobile phone, webpage only takes up about one fourth of my screen. The rest is just white space. I've been trying to find content all over the web see how I can resolve this issue, but wasn't able to. Does anyone know what's going on and how I can fix this?

```
    
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  
  --red-accent-color:rgb(204, 0, 0);
  --blue-accent-color:rgb(26, 117, 255);
  --dark-blue-accent-color:rgb(36, 36, 143);
  --white-accent-color:rgb(242, 242, 242);
  --default-font-family: calibri;
}
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
nav{
  color:var(--white-accent-color);
  background-color:var(--dark-blue-accent-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:left;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
  animation:fade-in 0.5s forwards;
}



#nav-content-list li{
  margin:0px 0px 0px 50px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#nav-content-list li a{
  color:var(--white-accent-color);

main{
  color:var(--white-accent-color);
  background-image:url("https://capitalplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Interior-Design.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  font-family:var(--default-font-family);
  position:relative;
  height:650px;
  z-index:1;
}


main::before{ 
  background-color:var(--blue-accent-color);
  opacity:0.5;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
  filter:blur(10px);

}

footer{
  background-color:gray;
}
```

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/chPZg.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chPZg.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZPYG.png)[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `html` and `body` elements heights are solely determined by their content.

So, as you noticed,

```
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

won't fill the entire screen.

To override this, add

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

to the `body` styling.
To verify that this worked, just set the `body`'s `background-color` to a color distinguishable from white.

---

This does not guarantee the actual content to fill the page, though. For that, you might want to look into using `display: flex;` or `display: grid;`.

You could use `flex` to make `main` fill the rest of the space of `body` not occupied by `nav` and the `footer`.

Here's a minimal example:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --blue-accent-color: rgb(26, 117, 255);
}

html {
  width: 100%,
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%,
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

/* --- */

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    background-color: var(--blue-accent-color);
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>NAV</p>
</nav>
<main>
  <p>MAIN</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>FOOTER</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: TARN4T1ON check out the pic of the home page I added.

Comment: @SebastianGalazka Could you maybe post the HTML too? Based on the CSS, it should actually fill the background horizontally just fine. Without the HTML, my best guess would be the ```meta``` ```viewport```, but that's really based on nothing.

Comment: you can view the HTML and CSS code here: https://codepen.io/SGalazka97/pen/QWGypBB